# How could I check if a user has a role in discord.NET?

Tags: c#, discord.net

I'm trying to find a way to check if a user has X role and performing something if they don't, similar on how it logs it to the console if you use `[RequireUserPermission(GuildPermission.Administrator)]`, just I don't want it to log to the console, EX:

```
if (has role)
{
    // do stuff
} else
{
    // do stuff
}
```

The command I'm trying to implement it into

```
[Command("clear")]
[RequireUserPermission(GuildPermission.ManageRoles)]
public async Task Clear(int amount)
{

    IEnumerable<IMessage> messages = await Context.Channel.GetMessagesAsync(amount + 1).FlattenAsync();
    await ((ITextChannel)Context.Channel).DeleteMessagesAsync(messages);

    const int delay = 3000;
    IUserMessage m = await ReplyAsync($"I have deleted {amount} messages");

    await Task.Delay(delay);
    await m.DeleteAsync();

    Console.Write(amount + " was cleared in a channel");
}
```

Comment: Checking if a user has a role vs if a user has a given permission are two separate things. You should clarify which you are attempting to do. Also, the library does not log precondition results to console by default. You'd be the one logging it, so if you don't want to log to console, simply review your code for where you are currently doing that.

Answer (score 1):

As akac pointed out the precondition you mentioned `[RequireUserPermission(...)]` checks if any of the roles assigned to a user gives them the permission to do a specific task. Consider the following example. You create a role called "Moderators" and enable the permission "Manage Messages". You then add the precondition `[RequireUserPermission(ChannelPermission.ManageMessages)]` to your `Clear()` method. Your `Clear()` method will now work for anybody in the "Moderators" role because they have permission to manage messages. It will also allow anybody in any other roles with the same permission to use it.

However, if you later decide you don't want "Moderators" to be able to manage messages and remove the permission from that role, your precondition will then automatically stop anyone in that role from using the `Clear` command.

If you check the users roles instead of their permissions, the users with the "Moderators" role would still be able to use the `Clear` command to delete messages even though you've removed the permission to manage messages from that role.

If the only reason you want to check the role instead of using the precondition to check their permissions is because you don't want it to log to the console, then this is probably the wrong approach for you. Instead you should consider sticking with the precondition and look at how you're handling the logging to prevent that message from being logged to the console.

If you would still like to check the user's roles, then here is an example of how you could do that in the `Clear()` method you provided. You will need to add `using System.Linq;` to the top of the file and replace `"RoleName"` in the second `if` statement with the name of the role you want to check.

```
public async Task Clear(int amount)
{
    // Get the user that executed the command cast it to SocketGuildUser
    // so we can access the Roles property
    if (Context.User is SocketGuildUser user)
    {
        // Check if the user has the requried role
        if (user.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "RoleName"))
        {
            IEnumerable<IMessage> messages = await Context.Channel.GetMessagesAsync(amount + 1).FlattenAsync();
            await((ITextChannel) Context.Channel).DeleteMessagesAsync(messages);

            const int delay = 3000;
            IUserMessage m = await ReplyAsync($"I have deleted {amount} messages");

            await Task.Delay(delay);
            await m.DeleteAsync();

            Console.Write(amount + " was cleared in a channel");
        }
        else
        {
            await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Sorry, you don't have permission to do that.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's simpler to use `.Any` instead of `.Where` and `.FirstOrDefault` with a null check

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue a couple of days ago, my solution was to create a custom attribute that inherited from `Discord.Commands.PreconditionAttribute`

I discovered this as I use dotPeek on my Visual Studio install to decompile and read how the command service actually works, as I wanted to know how their attributes worked as well. As part of the command service's execution of the command it checks all preconditions for each command, and only when each are satisfied does it execute the function.

This class has a function called `CheckPermissionsAsync`

Here is a sample that should work for you:

```
public class RequiresRoleAttribute : PreconditionAttribute
{
    private string m_role;

    public RequiresRoleAttribute (string role)
    {
        m_role = role;
    }

    public override async Task<PreconditionResult> CheckPermissionsAsync(ICommandContext context, CommandInfo command, IServiceProvider services)
    {
        if (context.User is SocketGuildUser sgu)
        {
            if (sgu.Roles.Select(x => x.Name == m_name).Contains(m_name)
            {
                return PreconditionResult.FromSuccess();
            }
        }

        return PreconditionResult.FromError($"The user doesn't have the role '{m_name}'");
    }
}
```

And the use:

```
[Command("clear")]
[RequiresRole("RoleName")]
public async Task Clear(int amount)
{

    IEnumerable<IMessage> messages = await Context.Channel.GetMessagesAsync(amount + 1).FlattenAsync();
    await ((ITextChannel)Context.Channel).DeleteMessagesAsync(messages);

    const int delay = 3000;
    IUserMessage m = await ReplyAsync($"I have deleted {amount} messages");

    await Task.Delay(delay);
    await m.DeleteAsync();

    Console.Write(amount + " was cleared in a channel");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you do:

You use the RequireRoles attribute.

It has 4 various ways: All, any, specified only, none

Let's say you want to make a ban command, but only want admin and mods to be able to use it. You would do this:

```
    public class Moderation : BaseCommandModule
{
    [Command("ban")]
    [RequireRoles(RoleCheckMode.Any, "admin", "mod")]
    public async Task BanCommand(CommandContext ctx, DiscordMember name, [RemainingText] string reason)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What are you doing here is basically using a precondition to check if *any* of the user's roles have the `ManageRoles` permission, the description is confusing.

As far as I know, Discord.net doesn't log such errors, only puts the default error message into the `Result` of the command, which is then usually sent to the channel as a response. There clearly has to be some place where your code logs such errors.